# Busting cache on relation with Laravel 5.6

Tags: laravel

I have a model named `Tournament` where each `Tournament` is cached with some of its relations, using a key for each model (i.e. `tournament.1`).

```
return \Cache::remember('tournament.' . $id, 60*24*7, function() use ($id) {
    return Tournament::where('id', $id)
        ->with(['prizes', 'sponsor'])
        ->firstOrFail();
});
```

When I update on the relations, I would like to forget that tournament's key. I know I could use event like this:

```
public static function boot()
{
    static::saving(function ($prize) {
        \Cache::forget('tournament.' . $prize->tournament->id);
    });

    return parent::boot();
}
```

However, doing this means I have to repeat this code for all other relations as well. I could probably create a trait for this, but is there a better way of doing what I want to achieve?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up solving this using a trait.

```
namespace App\Traits;

trait ShouldCacheBust
{
/**
 * The "booting" method of the model.
 */
public static function boot()
{
    static::saving(function ($model) {
        $cacheKey = static::cacheBustKey($model);

        if ($cacheKey) {
            \Cache::forget($cacheKey);
        }
    });

    return parent::boot();
}

/**
 * Return the key to be removed from Cache
 * 
 * @param Model $model
 * @return string|null
 */
abstract public function cacheBustKey(Model $model);
}
```

Then using it like this:

```
/**
 * Return the key to be removed from Cache
 *
 * @param Model $model
 * @return mixed|string
 */
public static function cacheBustKey(Model $model)
{
    return 'tournament.' . $model->id;
}
```